# ASP.Net: Conditional Logic in a ListView's ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, listview, logic

I want to show certain parts of an `ItemTemplate` based according to whether a bound field is null.  Take for example the following code:

*(Code such as LayoutTemplate have been removed for brevity)*

```
<asp:ListView ID="MusicList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <%
                if (Eval("DownloadLink") != null)
                {
            %>
            <td>
                <a href="<%#Eval("DownloadLink") %>">Link</a>
            </td>
            <%
                } %>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The above gives the following run-time error:

> Databinding methods such as Eval(),
>   XPath(), and Bind() can only be used
>   in the context of a databound control.

**So how can put some conditional logic (like the above) in an `ItemTemplate` ?**

Comment: This is the kind of thing which is currently driving me a bit crazy.  This is so EASY in ASP.net MVC yet a total drama in webforms

Answer (score 38, accepted):

What about binding the "Visible" property of a control to your condition?  Something like:

```
<asp:ListView ID="MusicList" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
    <tr runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("DownloadLink") != null %>'>
        <td>
            <a href='<%#Eval("DownloadLink") %>'>Link</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Hmm interesting point...but isn't there some way of injecting logic blocks in the ItemTemplate?

Comment: modified your answer to return a bool instead of string

Comment: I've tried this recently and get a runtime error: "The server tag is not well formed."

Comment: I got the same thing @Kyle, if I find a work around, I'll be sure to post it.

Comment: Fixed the quotes in the anchor tag that were probably causing the "The server tag is not well formed." error.

Answer (score 9):

To resolve "The server tag is not well formed." for the answers involving visibility, remove quotes from the Visible= parameter.

So it will become:

```
<tr runat="server" Visible=<%# Eval("DownloadLink") != null ? true : false %>>
```

Comment: You can also just use single quotes around the condition. I had double quotes and got the "server tag is not well formed" but when I changed them to single quotes it worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not recommending this as a good approach but you can work around this issue by capturing the current item in the OnItemDataBound event, storing it in a public property or field and then using that in your conditional logic.

For example:

```
<asp:ListView ID="MusicList" OnItemDataBound="Item_DataBound" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <%
                if (CurrentItem.DownloadLink != null)
                {
            %>
            <td>
                <a href="<%#Eval("DownloadLink") %>">Link</a>
            </td>
            <%
                } %>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And on the server side add the following code to your code behind file:

```
public MusicItem CurrentItem { get; private set;}

protected void Item_DataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   CurrentItem = (MusicItem) e.Item.DataItem;
}
```

Note that this trick will not work in an `UpdatePanel` control.

Answer (score 3):

If you have 2 different structure that are to be rendered according to a condition then use panels

```
<asp:ListView ID="MusicList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <asp:Panel ID="DownloadNull" runat="server" Visible="<%# Eval("DownloadLink") == null %>" >
            <td> Album Description BlaBlaBla <img src="../images/test.gif"> </td>
            </asp:Panel>

            <asp:Panel ID="DownloadNotNull" runat="server" Visible="<%# Eval("DownloadLink") != null %>" >
            <td> Album Description BlaBlaBla <img src="../images/test.gif">
                <a href='<%# Eval("DownloadLink")' >Download</a>
                ..... 
            </td>
            </asp:Panel>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```