# Dynamically adding class to a ASP.NET WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to dynamically allocate a css class to a `tr` in an `ItemTemplate` in a `asp:ListView`. I want to apply this class if a boolean value in the backing model equals true. In this case the property is `BackingModelProperty`

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083829/asp-net-conditional-logic-in-a-listviews-itemtemplate) the `Visible` property is being dynamically set based on the data the OP is trying to display in their `asp:ListView`.

So far I have tried:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr runat="server" class="<%# (((bool)Eval("BackingModelProperty")) == true) ? 'test-css-class' : null %>">
    ...
</ItemTemplate>
```

However, I get an error

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between `char` and `<null>`

So instead I tried using the `CssClass` attribute instead of `class`, this also didn't work. I have tried casting to a integer and checking whether the value was `== 1`. This also failed with the same error message.

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `runat=server` (and do not use `'`)

```
<tr class="<%# (((bool)Eval("BackingModelProperty")) == true) ? "test-css-class" : null %>">
```

And make sure that `BackingModelProperty` is, or can be converted to a boolean.

Comment: This appears to have worked, thanks! Out of interest, why was the `runat=server` problematic?

Comment: Because then it becomes a `HtmlControl`, which would require binding it's properties different (this time with singe quotes: `Property='<%#  Eval("Item") %>'`), and will require items of `HtmlTableCell` and presumably a parent `table runat=server`. By then you are wrapping a GridView inside another table AND server control.